# why when i add width into list of css, the list become vertical instead of horizontal

Tags: html, css, xhtml

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
 ul {list-style:none; margin:0; padding:0; }
  li{float: left; border:dotted; text-align: center; width: 100px;}




  </style>

</head>

<body>

     <ul>
       <li>home</li>
       <li id="up">pages

       <ul class="down">
       <li>a</li>
       <li>b</li>
       <li>c</li>                  
      </ul>

       </li>

     </ul>


</body>



</html>
```

This is my code, in the css:`

```
li{float: left; border:dotted; text-align: center; }`
```

when i didnt put width property, the element a, b, c goes horizontallaly
but why after i put in width it became horizontally?I thought width only set the width of the element

Comment: sry but try the code out, i'm frm Malaysia

Comment: Use http://jsfiddle.net/ so that we don't have to.

Answer (score 0):

The `a`, `b`, `c` list items are children of the `pages` list item. Your CSS seletor `li` is applying the 100px width to all list items on the page, therefore the `a`, `b`, `c` list items respect the width of their parent and fall on new lines.

If you only want to give the `a`, `b`, `c` items a width then use a different selector to exclude the parent item, such as:

```
ul li ul li { width:100px; }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, your `<ul>` doesn't have enough room to let the `<li>`s expand horizontally.
`float: left` will try to keep all `<li>`s on the same 'row', but if there is no room they will just drop down.
Try adding this to the `ul {}` styles:

`width: 400px`